# Reading the contents of a bootable Linux USB memory stick

Tags: windows, system-installation

From my Windows machine I was able to [successfully create installation media for Linux](https://ubuntu.com/download/iot/installation-media#windows) on a USB memory stick, which I then used for installing Linux (Ubuntu) on a target machine.  Now that the installation is complete, I want to see what file(s) got written to the memory stick in the first place.  However, Windows is giving me the following message:

> You need to format the disk in drive blahblahblah before you can use
> it.

So is there a way for me to read the Linux installation media memory stick from Windows?

Answer (score 0):

Linux drives typically use the `ext4` filesystem, which Windows cannot read out of the box. You could try looking at [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/37512/how-to-read-ext4-partitions-on-windows) for ways to read an ext4 partition on Windows.